# Web-server-video remote access

Tags: rosbridge, camera, video, web, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to access the web-video-server. I got it to work on localhost, the url in the doc works and everything is fine. However I can't access it remotely ( on a different laptop on the same network) or from a remote connection.
(Note that my router gives me a ipv6 address, I tried http://[myip]:8080 without success ).

What is the best way to get my camera to stream on a webbrowser that is remote ? Should I use port forwarding ?

---

Edit:  Thanks !

My router gives me an IPV6 by default, I haven't been able to switch to IPV4. Also I sort of want to be able to do this accross different network ( depending on where the robot is connected to wifi) without requiring a specific setup ( like forcing a static IP)
I'm not sure what's the best way for this, maybe setting up a VPN...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272309/web-server-video-remote-access/) by [Clement Jambou](https://answers.ros.org/users/32146/clement-jambou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-10-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-13**:
@Clement Jambou: please don't post answers, unless you are answering your own question. For everyting else, please use comments, or update your original question text.

I've already merged your answer into your OP, but do please keep it in mind next time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am able to access the steam on a different laptop, same network, using IPv4. Have you tried that?

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 545 on 2017-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0